# Unable to read thread page after successful login with JSOUP

Tags: parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to read a forum page with Jsoup but I'm not able to do so. I'm successfully logged in, than I'm able to read the first page or list page. But when I go to the thread page, it is giving me 403. Here's the code:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://picturepub.net/index.php?login/login").method(Connection.Method.GET)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0").timeout(0).execute();

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://picturepub.net/index.php?login/login").data("cookieexists", "false").data("cookie_check", "1").data("login", "swordblazer")
    .data("password", "picturepub").data("register", "0").data("redirect", "/index.php").cookies(loginForm.cookies())
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0").post();

doc = loginForm.parse();

Map<String, String> cookies = loginForm.cookies();

List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> threadUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
int h = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    if (i == 1)
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://picturepub.net/index.php?forums/photoshoots-magazines.51/")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0").cookies(cookies).get();
    else
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://picturepub.net/index.php?forums/photoshoots-magazines.51/page-" + i)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0").cookies(cookies).get();

    // get all links
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    System.out.println(doc.title());
    for (Element element : links) {
    if (element.absUrl("href").contains("threads")) {
        String linkImage = element.absUrl("href");
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(linkImage).cookies(cookies).get();

        if (!threadUrls.contains(linkImage)) {
        threadUrls.add(linkImage);
        h++;
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You get `403` probably because you are missing some parameter/cookie. If you've figured how to login than use the same method to monitor the trafic between your browser and the site and see what your browser is sending.

Comment: I did that. Is there anything else other than cookies which I need to send to the server?

Comment: Cookies and the needed parameters.

Comment: I inspected everything with firebug. I'm unable to find anything. Can you help?

Comment: Can you add a picture showing which thread are you trying to read? There are plenty of links at that page...

Comment: Any one thread. The first one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130721/discussion-between-tdg-and-user236928).

Answer (score 0):

JSoup connections are unrelated to each other, so they do not share the "login state/session". You must replicate the state between them yourself carefully. You're getting HTTP 403 because of a few reasons:

- The `loginForm` response does not return authentication cookies, and you cannot use them for authorized resources, however you use these cookies later.
- To obtain the authentication cookies you must to obtain the cookies from the `POST http://picturepub.net/index.php?login/login` response, and do not convert it to a document. The second request must be declared as a POST request using `method(POST)`.
- The failing request, `Jsoup.connect(linkImage).cookies(cookies).get();` misses `User-Agent`.

---

In order to make your code less error-prone, you should consider refactoring as one of the things that would make your code more robust.

```java
private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0";
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://picturepub.net/index.php";
private static final int PAGE_COUNT = 20;

static void grab()
        throws IOException {
    out.println("Getting the login form...");
    final Response getLoginFormResponse = prepareConnection(GET, "?login/login", emptyMap())
            .execute();
    out.println("Posting the login data...");
    // Avoid converting to document when it's unnecessary and use `execute()`
    final Response postLoginFormResponse = prepareConnection(POST, "?login/login", getLoginFormResponse.cookies())
            .data("cookieexists", "false")
            .data("cookie_check", "1")
            .data("login", ...YOUR USERNAME...)
            .data("password", ...YOUR PASSWORD...)
            .data("register", "0")
            .data("redirect", "/index.php")
            .execute();
    // Obtain the authentication cookies
    final Map<String, String> cookies = postLoginFormResponse.cookies();
    // If you want to discard duplicates, just don't use lists -- sets are designed for unique elements.
    // The `h` is unnecessary because you can query the collection for its size: threadUrls.size()
    final Collection<String> threadUrls = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for ( int i = 1; i <= PAGE_COUNT; i++ ) {
        out.printf("Page #%d...\n", i);
        final Document getPageDocument = prepareConnection(GET, "?forums/photoshoots-magazines.51/" + (i == 1 ? "" : "page-" + i), cookies)
                .execute()
                .parse();
        out.printf("Page #%d: %s\n", i, getPageDocument.title());
        // `a[href*=threads/]` is a selector to obtain all links having the "threads/" in <A> element URLs -- no need to check for substring later
        // The following code uses Java 8 streams to filter out duplicate links on the page
        final Iterable<String> hrefs = getPageDocument.select("a[href*=threads/]")
                .stream()
                .map(e -> e.absUrl("href"))
                .collect(toSet());
        for ( final String href : hrefs ) {
            out.printf("Probing: %s ... ", href);
            final Response analyzeMeResponse = prepareConnection(GET, stripBaseUrl(href), cookies)
                    .execute();
            threadUrls.add(href);
            out.println("Done!");
        }
    }
    out.println(threadUrls);
}

private static String stripBaseUrl(final String url)
        throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if ( !url.startsWith(BASE_URL) ) {
        // This must not happen for a well-written parser
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(url);
    }
    return url.substring(BASE_URL.length());
}

// Just make sure that a particular connection is:
// * bound to the BASE_URL defined above
// * bound to a specific HTTP method
// * follows redirects
// * User-Agent is set
// * cookies are always set
private static Connection prepareConnection(final Method method, final String url, final Map<String, String> cookies) {
    return connect(BASE_URL + url)
            .followRedirects(true)
            .method(method)
            .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
            .cookies(cookies);
}
```

The code above is based on `org.jsoup:json:1.10.1` since the previous JSoup versions cannot handle [HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) that is used by that web-site.